# Ad mob in android how to set treashold

Tags: android, admob

How to set  ad mob  click threshold  and  hide  the  ads...  Are else they used  to   block the  app....  I account  is  blocked  sevaral time for  not  setting the  threshold. How  to set  it  help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `onDismissScreen` to "count" the number of time ads were served, clicked and dismissed. Using this count, you can stop serving ads when the value exceeds a threshold that you choose.

Comment: Do  you  know  what  is  Max click  threshold  for  the  ad mob

Comment: I don't think it works this way. It probably takes into consideration the frequency, the IP address and lots of other factors. You probably get banned for repeated suspicious activity rather than exceeding some threshold at one time.

Comment: If you are setting this up to prevent someone from deliberately getting you banned, its fine. If you are thinking of using a hack to click ads while staying within a threshold, I think AdMob will be on to you in a flash.